# Adding previously downloaded .deb files to apt using command line

Tags: command-line, software-installation, debian

How can I add previously downloaded .deb files to apt using command line so that they will not be downloaded again when I use `sudo apt-get install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy it to /var/cache/apt/archives with the following command:

```
sudo cp filename.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

You may have to rename the deb files according to the cache, so start to download it with `apt-get`, get the name of the cached file from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` then rename your file and copy it there overwriting the incomplete download and start `apt-get` again.

Of course you don't need this if you are copying from an old cache :)

Comment: Does copying to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` means that they are recognized?

Comment: @user69453 Yes, it is where apt-get stores its cache, so if you copy your deb file with the correct filename it should install it instead of downloading it again.